# Is this an abuse of 'dynamic'?

Tags: c#

Is the following use of 'dynamic', in the method IsUnixNewline, good or bad?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] bytes = { 32, 32, 32, 10 };
        string text  = "hello\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i) {
            if (IsUnixNewline(bytes, i)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Found Unix newline in 'bytes'.");
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i) {
            if (IsUnixNewline(text, i)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Found Unix newline in 'text'.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static bool IsUnixNewline(dynamic array, int index)
    {
        return array[index] == '\n' && (index == 0 || array[index - 1] != '\r');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dynamic and not char or string in this case?

Comment: I don't see how IsUnixNewline could use char or string.

Comment: @Roger byte array and string is passed to method. look again.

Comment: I wonder if you could use a Linq (i.e., [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) ) to make your byte array into a char array, thus sidestepping the whole problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would say "yes" - `dynamic` is not *required* here, and adds a lot of uncertainty about what it will do at runtime (and, of course, throws away static compiler checking); better to just use a few overloads in this case, IMO:

```
    static bool IsUnixNewline(char[] array, int index)
    {
        return array[index] == '\n' && (index == 0 || array[index - 1] != '\r');
    }
    static bool IsUnixNewline(byte[] array, int index)
    {
        return array[index] == '\n' && (index == 0 || array[index - 1] != '\r');
    }
    static bool IsUnixNewline(string array, int index)
    {
        return array[index] == '\n' && (index == 0 || array[index - 1] != '\r');
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

rewritten (**without a compiler!**) to make use of `char[]` instead of `dynamic`.
You need to take care of the correct encoding, when converting `byte[]` to `string`, but you should get the idea.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] bytes = { 32, 32, 32, 10 };
        string text  = "hello\n";
        char[] characterArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes).ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < characterArray.Length; ++i) {
            if (IsUnixNewline(characterArray, i)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Found Unix newline in 'bytes'.");
                break;
            }
        }

        characterArray = text.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < characterArray .Length; ++i) {
            if (IsUnixNewline(characterArray, i)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Found Unix newline in 'text'.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static bool IsUnixNewline(char[] array, int index)
    {
        return array[index] == '\n' && (index == 0 || array[index - 1] != '\r');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion bad, as this

```
        var b = IsUnixNewline(new NewObjectNotSupportingIndexer(), 0);
```

will go through the compiler perfectly fine during development, but fail during runtime.
Why sacrificing type safety when you don´t have too? Dynamic is of great help if you don´t know the type during developemt (ComInterop), but in this case I think it causes more damage than help.

Comment: Hmm, how else could IsUnixNewline be written?  I can't find an interface like IIndexable.

Answer (score 1):

the dynamic keyword causes runtime type checking instead of compiletime type checking. I cannot for the life of me see why this simple operation explicitly requires runtime type checking. the same could very easily be achieved without dynamic. I don't know if I'd classify this as an abuse of dynamic, I'd certainly classify it as unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

First it's important to recognize that a `byte` is *not* a character. Therefore, to convert those you need to first apply an encoding (even if that's only the `ASCII` or `Default` encoding). Doing that with the `GetString` method of `Encoding` will give you a string, making the distinction between the two types void.

However, to answer more generally, you should always try and see what the types have in common. For instance, both the `char[]` and `string` implement `IEnumerable<char>`. Therefore, instead of checking each position for being a unit newline, why not have a method which checks all characters using an enumerator?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        byte[] bytes = { 32, 32, 32, 10 };
        string text  = "hello\n";

        if (HasUnixNewline(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytes))) {
            Console.WriteLine("Found Unix newline in 'bytes'.");
        }
        if (HasUnixNewline(text)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Found Unix newline in 'text'.");
        }
   }

    static bool HasUnixNewline(IEnumerable<char> chars) {
        bool prevIsCR = false;
        foreach (char ch in chars) {
            if ((ch == '\n') && (!prevIsCR)) {
                return true;
            }
            prevIsCR = ch == '\r';
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The other variant would be to use the so-called [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), that is, an (often stateless) object wrapping the original instance and providing alternative interfaces. In this case, you could easily implement an interface which exposes just the read indexer and returns characters, and then use this in your `IsUnixNewLine` method. Or you could apply that same pattern to avoid the use of the `Encoding` class in my sample by writing an adapter which implements `IEnumerable<char>` and wraps an `IEnumerable<byte>`.